# Windows - how to make in windows service which can check google chrome is running or not if not then execute it

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, windows-services

I have a kiosk in Railway where i am using this batch file, but the problem is at 8AM there are too many school kids in front of the machine, when they see a Command prompt, they press the X icon and close my application, i get then report that my software is not working, but it was actually switched off by someone while starting.

How can i make this script execute when-ever chrome.exe is not running please? (for example if someone kills it using mouse or touch screen)

```
timeout 5 > nul
::@start /b cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk 
@start /b cmd /c "C:\Users\tpt\Downloads\old-chrome\chrome64_49.0.2623.75\chrome.exe" --kiosk
```

Comment: Why are you launching chrome from cmd? Why not start chrome directly?

Comment: Because when the system boot, internet comes after few seconds or few minutes therefore i need to have BATCH

Comment: Then make the chrome homepage a locally hosted page that implements the delay via javascript - it can retry a fetch of some kind until it succeeds (proving that the internet is up) and then navigate to the internet hosted site.

Comment: OK - thank you, great idea. 1) So locally i run NodeJS 2) using NodeJS i detect if internet is on or off 3) if off stay in the same page, if on then redirect to https://realwebsite.com ?

Comment: That would work and (potentially) solve any script sandboxing issues caused by trying to run javascript in a file:// hosted page.

Comment: Excellent. you are guru, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set up kiosks before and replaced the Windows Explorer shell with a custom application.

Change the Shell value in the following registry key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

You may be able to just run chrome like this without having to call it via a cmd shell.

Comment: But, the internet comes after 5 minute or sometimes within few seconds. How can i tell Chrome to get launch but do not stay in the offline page forever or so?